# Extract pages from DOC to new DOC

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

We are developing a printing server that allows user to upload a DOC and print it out via HP ePrint. It needs to support page extraction.

I tried to use macro (with the help of Adobe Acrobat Reader Pro and MS Word) to extract pages into PDF. But it turns out that the size of PDF may be larger in size than expected.

Is there any way to extract pages (without lossing format - E.g. Table in DOC) from DOC to DOC, so that the size can be approximately the size?

Comment: I've not touched MS Office in some years, but I'd personally try the equivalent of the VBA system (is it .net now?) to extract page content. Even if this is possible, I can foresee problems - text is generally flowed from one page to the next, so if you want to capture a page _as is_, you'll have to grab the text/graphic elements and copy them into a new doc manually. Interesting problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult requirement.  It sounds like you have run into 2 problems (large PDFs and format loss) at the outset.  You should probably say more about what you mean by "extraction" and why PDF is part of your solution because that's quite different from "upload and print" and "doc to doc".  That way readers will have more suggestions for you.

I would suggest you try to approach the problem from a different angle if possible, because I suspect that you are unlikely to achive a good, efficent, stable result.  One possible approach is to turn the DOC into PDF and then use iText or some other PDF library to manipulate the PDF before printing.  It really depends on what you are trying to achieve - the specifics of your extract/merge/convert.

Comment: I agree with this, and would add that if @SkyEagle888 wants to preserve format, don't use PDF. It's a great format, but once you use it, the meaning of each element disappears - it becomes just a bunch of graphics and text elements.